# Is it necessary to have valid CSS?

Tags: css

Is it necessary to have valid CSS? I am using Twitter Bootstrap for rapid web development and after running the two main Bootstrap style sheets through the W3C CSS Validator, I noticed about 600 errors.

My question is, my site looks good so why is it so important for the CSS to be valid?

Comment: what are some of the validation errors?

Comment: If the validation errors are about vendor-specific prefixes, ignore them. Otherwise, that's a problem with Bootstrap. Like @scunliffe asked — what are some of the errors you get?

Comment: If you run any site that uses Bootstrap through the W3C CSS validation tool, you'll see the error messages that are being thrown up. Too many to list here right now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is absolutely necessary to have valid CSS. CSS is a programming language and as such, you must follow its language rules. Just because browsers tend to accept invalid HTML and try to render it, it doesn't make generating ill-formatted HTML a good practice. The same is true to CSS, although - fortunately - CSS rules are quite a bit stricter than HTML rules.

Another reason is that valid CSS has guaranteed behavior - if you write a rule, you can expect that rule to behave a certain way. (Buggy browsers, like all versions of IE aside.) If your CSS is invalid, any behavior you get is undefined and it may break when a patch release is issued for any of the browsers that you use for testing. Your CSS won't necessarily break but when you write invalid CSS, you get no guarantees of any behavior - you simply get *some* behavior that may seem correct to you but that may change any time.

If you have correct CSS mixed in with incorrect CSS, browsers tend to ignore the invalid parts (just how the specification tells them to) but each browser does it slightly differently. Similarly, while many people advise to use CSS hacks, I'd say not to, for the above reasons.

Comment: May be "preferably" not "absolutely". Because reality is that we must support browsers our users use.

Comment: @Grimmo I mostly agree with your comment. The reason I used absolutely is because many readers may interpret "preferably" in a permissive way - that is, they may assume that it's ok to have 'bad' CSS and it's ok to rely on the browser to sort it out.

Answer (score 3):

The CSS doesn't have to be valid to work. Browsers simply ignore the CSS that they don't understand.

Validating the CSS is a method to test if it follows the specification. If it does, any browser that is up to date with the specification used will understand the CSS.

Answer (score 3):

It's somewhat of a debated topic really.  The W3C tools are certainly good to use, but they tend to not account for a lot of modern code.  Naturally, it's difficult for them to not only advance standards, but also make sure the tools they offer are accountable to new and inventive code.

In order to get websites to look good in all browser and across all platforms requires people to maybe stretch outside of the norms that otherwise would be "valid".  It's tough to argue against a site that works perfect cross browser and platform even if the CSS isn't 100% spotless.  That's my two cents.

Answer (score 3):

Your CSS doesn't need to be valid (depending on who you ask), but if it is invalid, you should have a reason for the invalidity:

```
audio,
canvas,
video {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

The validator has a parse error here because of the asterisk at the beginning of property.  This is a obscure but recognized hack for targeting Internet Explorer.  Other browsers will ignore the properties that it won't recognize but IE6/7 will read properties with asterisks.

---

```
input:-moz-placeholder,
textarea:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder,
textarea:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
}
```

The validator error here is a result of vendor-specific pseudo-classes.  Note than unlike unrecognized properties, if a browser doesn't recognize the selector the *entire rule* will be ignored so the vendor placeholder extensions need to be separate rules.  This happens even when using the comma operator so:

```
input::-moz-placeholder,
input::-ms-input-placeholder,
input::-webkit-input-placeholder, {
  color: #999999;
}
```

would be ignored in *all* browsers unless they recognized all three vendor prefixes.

---

```
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fffbb450', endColorstr='#fff89406', GradientType=0);
```

This is the old-style IE extension for gradients.  It ripples and causes a number of errors in the validator even though IE follows it and other browsers will not quietly ignore it.

---

```
width: auto\9;
```

The \9 is another IE hack that targets IE<=8

---

The bottom line is that if you are doing something non-standard, make sure you know *why* you are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Now a days there are different number of browsers with different number of versions.Some supports lot but some are not.So when you include styles it is always not possible to fit 100 % perfect.If your style works without any problem ok.But when it goes to different browsers if you get problem related CSS , You have to take care otherwise no problem.

Answer (score 0):

yes its important, most of browsers follows the w3c standard when they load the html page. if your page don't have the valid css, in different browser it might appear different ways. Old internet explorers didn't followed the W3c standards which cost alot to the developers result in developer need always extra css for the IE to display page properly.